# TweenMax Animating before ScrollMagic

Tags: jquery, css, animation, gsap

## TweenMax running before ScrollMagic

I am trying to make the header shrink in size on scrolling through the page using `TweenMax` and `ScrollMagic` but the animation is triggering without waiting for the Scroll.

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var header = $('header')

    //init the controller
    var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
    var tween = TweenMax.to(header ,1 ,{height: 100});
    var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        triggerElement: header
    })
    .setTween(tween)
    .addTo(controller);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #e95849;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

li {
  float: right;
  color: #000;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}

header {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 150px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.5/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/animation.gsap.min.js"></script>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul id="animate">
                <li>ABOUT</li>
                <li>WORK</li>
                <li>DESIGN</li>
                <li>CONTACT</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div style="height: 2000px"></div>
```

I have also the scripts in the following order -

1. Jquery
2. TweenMax
3. ScrollMagic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script is triggered because the `header` element is already at the trigger position (= the top of the viewport). Add `offset: 1` to the scene - this will cause it to wait until you scroll down at least one pixel. (change that value to whatever you like)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var header = $('header')

    //init the controller
    var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
    var tween = TweenMax.to(header ,1 ,{height: 100});
    var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        triggerElement: header,
        offset: 1
    })
    .setTween(tween)
    .addTo(controller);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #e95849;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

li {
  float: right;
  color: #000;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}

header {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 150px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.5/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/animation.gsap.min.js"></script>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul id="animate">
                <li>ABOUT</li>
                <li>WORK</li>
                <li>DESIGN</li>
                <li>CONTACT</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div style="height: 2000px"></div>
```